# Rigid Body Physics: Having multiple rigid body worlds

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, baking

In Blender's manual (v2.78) it says that it is possible to have multiple rigid body worlds: https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/rigid_body/world.html.
I figured that this would enable me to have multiple independent rigid body simulations going on, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as one may only set one active group in Scene>RigidBodyWorld.
Or alternatively, I was hoping that this would enable me to bake one rigid body world group which is ought to simulate at one point in my total animation, and use a different world for a different rigid body simulation which should play at some future time in my total animation. However, this didn't work out either, as there is only one cache: if I change the active rigid body world group, the current bake gets transferred to the objects in the new rigid body world group.
It'd be nice if these independent simulations could have a different "Speed" value as well.

**Question:**
Is it somehow possible to have multiple independent rigid body simulations? 
Or is it somehow possible to bake one rigid body world (apart from bake to key-frame, which finalises the simulation) in one cache (just like there are multiple caches for cloth simulations), and another rigid body world to another cache, and then have them both play if the animation is played (Alt+A)?

**My current work-around (not ideal):**
Have all simulations live in the same rigid body world, and use key-framing on the "dynamic" box to activate/deactivate the independent simulations. This is not ideal, as I have to re-simulate everything if the bake is freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the manual does not say that you can have multiple rigid body worlds. What they mean is that you can have multiple groups that can be selected in the "Rigid Body World" panel. The name of the default group is "RigidBodyWorld", which makes things a bit confusing. I explained these concepts in more detail in my answer to this question: [Rigid Body World (Groups) Explained](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71474/rigid-body-world-groups-explained)

At a given time (and within a given scene) you can have only one rigid body simulation.

A workaround could be to use multiple scenes (each scene can have its own "Rigid Body World" settings), and composite the results together.

Comment: Hmhm, that's what I figured. The problem of using multiple scenes is that the simulations cannot live in the same space (as in the camera turns around within a virtual world to switch between two independent simulations), right? Hence I will stick with keyframing the "dynamic" box anyway.